# How can I count different objects in a List that all share the same Interface?

Tags: vb.net

I have an object (`MyObj`) that itself will hold a List of other objects of various types and I want to count them as they are added to `MyObj`.  That's the simple explanation, anyways...

I have an Interface (`MyInterface`) that all sub-objects agree to.  `MyObj` has a `List(Of MyInterface`) property that all the sub-objects are added to.  `MyInterface` will expose a property that lets me figure out what subtype each object is (the sub-objects do not inherit from `MyObj` at all).

But I want to count these sub-objects as they are added to the list, and I'm trying to find a good way to do it.  I don't need to worry about decrementing the count, as I am going to mimic the behavior of String and just create a new instance of `MyObj` if it ever changes, so all my counts will start from 0.  This'll hit the garbage collector a bit, but I think this will allow for simpler (and safer) code.

The only sane way I can think of to count objects is a very large structure in `MyObj` that uses bytes to hold the count (I will never have more than 255 of any given sub-object in the list in `MyObj`).  But, even using bytes, this structure will be about 100-200 bytes big in memory (I have that many sub-objects), and I anticipate having a fair amount of `MyObj` copies running around, too.

I'll also need a large `Select Case` to know which count property to increment when a new sub-object is added.  This seems to be a bit ugly, though I've used this approach several times already.

What I am wondering is, instead of counting each object as it is added to the list, is there some way to query the list and count only the objects of a specific type?  I wouldn't need to store this anywhere, since it would be dynamic, like querying a database and asking for a count of a specific column or type of record.

I suspect Linq can do this, but Linq is also quite slow.  Are there other approaches?  Perhaps a predicate of some kind?

**EDIT:** I tink I want something like this in Linq, but I'm a bit confused on how to format it in VB (I am not a C# guy):

```
From i in MyObj.MyList Group i by i.GetType into g Let c as Int32 = g.Count()
```

And that's it so far.  I am still googling, but I am getting way too many C# and SQL references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MyObj.MyList.OfType(Of Int32)().Count()
```